# Should there be only one ViewModel class in MVVM pattern?

Tags: c#, mvvm, xamarin

I am trying to understand the MVVM pattern and there is some issue that is not clear. My Xamarin Forms application will have several Views (which is quite obvious). Must everyone of them be binded to different ModelView class? Or maybe there should be only one MV?

Comment: it depends.  Typically each View has it's own VM, but two similar views could share a VM.  It would be unusual for every View to use the same VM, but for a simple app that might make sense.

Answer (score 2):

**Yes and No**
**Yes** -> Basically the idea is that your `ViewModel` should only be used by one view. If you use a `ViewModel` to populate an area or whatever then that `ViewModel` is "reused" each time that view is presented in difference places.
**No** -> You can use multiple models in a view model. The purpose of the view model is to abstract away the business / data layer (i.e. the model).
However, using more than one model usually indicates that the view is too large. You might want to split it into user controls (which have their own view models).

References:

1. [With MVVM, does each UI window have its own ViewModel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2790230/with-mvvm-does-each-ui-window-have-its-own-viewmodel)
2. [In MVVM, is every ViewModel coupled to just one Model?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13085670/in-mvvm-is-every-viewmodel-coupled-to-just-one-model)

Answer (score 1):

I've always thought of "each View has its own VM" - the model as being a sub-set of a comprehensive design.

I will say from painful experience: do not design models in isolation based solely on the view/UI they support. Without a comprehensive model back end you will have a hard time integrating all of the pieces into a coherent, complete business model that works. Anemic classes, redundant bits, incomplete and wrong validations, same properties-different names, incompatibilities w/ existing code, gobs of hacky glue code, Programmers breaking each other's code, no re-usability, no reuse of existing classes. For us it all came to a head in a 3 month test-fail-fix tilt-a-whirl of embarrassment.